# solve initial value problem (linear differential equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To solve the initial value problem: $y' +2ty = e^{-t^2} , y(0) =y_0$

In which initial value $y_0$ comes from condition $y(2)=0$

Well, at least, I managed to solve the equation and find the general solution which is $y=te^{-t^2} + Ce^{-t^2}$.  I think? but idk how to solve it with particular with initial value :)

ty for help etc :)

Comment: integrating factor to do what? if you mean solve the differential equation I already did that by multiplying both sides with e^(t^2) and then I got (y*e(^t^2))' dy =1dt and then I multiply with e^-t^2 to get y by itself so I get y=te^(-t^2) + Ce^(-t^2) :) its the substition part when im supposed to find c or whatever, that is confusing with this y_0 stuff :P

Comment: Is it $y_0 = y(0)$ or $y_0 = y(2)$?

Comment: which initial valye y_0 comes from y(2)=0 that should be right.. sorry lol :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$y(t) = e^{-t^2} ( c_1 + t )$$

At $t_0 = 2, y(2) = 0$, so we have:

$$y(2) = e^{-4}(c_1 + 2)  = 0 \implies c_1 = -2$$

Hence

$$y(t) = e^{-t^2/2} (t - 2)$$